# Desktop Background

Tags: windows, desktop-customization

I set a desktop background picture by browsing an selecting it in the Windows 10 settings routine.

The latest update to W10 has set the background to solid white, and my selected picture is no longer shown as an option.

I cannot find the picture by searching my very large pictures library, and do not have a search argument for it.

Can you tell me how to find it?  I have spent nearly a day trying with no result.

Pretty Please??

Mike

Comment: Use `regedit` to go to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` and check if the value named `Wallpaper` contains the picture.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the *Microsoft* *Windows* Registry Editor can be scary for new users.

First try these two paths and see if you can find your picture:

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles`

`%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper`